# Scala List Conversion and Map application

Tags: scala

I am trying to do something that on the surface should be fairly simple. I am trying to convert a Java List to a Scala List then use the map method to apply a function to each element then return the list of the new elements.

I have added extra type info to try and confirm whats going on.

```
class Incidents extends AggregateBase {

  def toEvent(entry: EventStoreEntry) = entry.event match {

    case  "raised" =>  buildRaised(entry)

  }

  def buildRaised(entry: EventStoreEntry): IncidentsEventRaised = {

    return new IncidentsEventRaised(entry)
  }
}

def getAll(aggregateName: String, aggregateId: String): List[EventInstanceBase] = { 

    val aggregate = new Incidents()

    val entries:List[EventStoreEntry] = accessor.findAll(aggregateName, aggregateId).all().asScala.toList

    return entries.map((e:EventStoreEntry) => aggregate.toEvent(e)).asInstanceOf[List[EventInstanceBase]]
}
```

What happens is I get the following exception:

java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.runtime.BoxedUnit cannot be cast to EventInstanceBase

Can any one explain what is going on? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to provide explicit return type for this:

```
def toEvent(entry: EventStoreEntry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `return` keyword. It does not behave the same as java - it unwinds the stack by throwing a NonLocalReturn exception, which in this case is going to break your map call.

The return keyword should never be used inside scala files.